# How to pin element inside a horizontally scrollable div

Tags: html, css, css-position

If I have a button with `position: absolute` inside of a div with `overflow-x: auto` the button will snap to the edge of the container.

However, if the div's content overflows the horizontal width, the button stays pinned to its starting location within the container after scrolling.

[image: Screenshot example]

It seems `absolute` ought to fix it to the side, but doesn't seem to do the trick

Is there any way to pin the child content to the right side of a horizontally scrollable div?

#### Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example

```css
.container {
    width: 20rem;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.container button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre class="container">Multi Line Text
Long piece of content that overflows the width of container<button>Copy</button></pre>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Position `fixed` won't work because it's always relative to the page. You want to nest the elements inside another component that has a position `relative`. The elements inside will be positioned based on this parent.

```css
.top-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 20rem;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.container {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
.top-container button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <button>Copy</button>
  <pre class="container">Long piece of content that overflows the width of container</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I got was using `position: sticky`.

```css
.container {
    width: 20rem;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.container button {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre class="container">Long piece of content that overflows the width of container<button>Copy</button></pre>
```

Comment: @KyleMit changed it to `sticky`, but the answer seems better 

Comment: @Rojo sticky was a good idea (it's clearly under used) but it doesn't work for this situation because it sticks to the viewport (top: 0; right: 0) when the element gets outside of the viewport. Here is a great article on sticky and when to use it: https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: @LoïcBellemare-Alford Thanks! I had only learned about sticky when I searched for CSS `position` types...