# Absolute alignment of multiple elements in horizontal scrolling div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a list of elements inside a table-like container with horizontal scrolling. Each element has the same width but might have a different height. I would like each of these elements to have a button in its top-right corner, but I don't want this button to scroll out of view when the elements become too long.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964424/how-to-pin-element-inside-a-horizontally-scrollable-div) that solves the same problem, but for only one item in a scrolling div. It relies on positioning the button relative to the container, which I can't do due to the list of elements.

My current attempt looks like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.table {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  /* 
  If the row isn't relative, all buttons stick to the
  container top.
  
  However, the buttons are now also out of view 
  due to the overflow.
  */
  position: relative;
  
  /* Just to make the content overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* For a clearer distinction between rows */
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.button {
  /* The button needs to be in line with the parent row */
  top: 0;
  
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        Some content so long that it for sure overflows the container, and thus a horizontal scroll is needed.
      </div>
      <button class="button">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        Some content so long that it for sure overflows the container, and thus a horizontal scroll is needed.
        <br>
        This one is however a bit taller than the other items.
      </div>
      <button class="button">2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        Some content so long that it for sure overflows the container, and thus a horizontal scroll is needed.
      </div>
      <button class="button">3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set the position of the button using jquery. but instead of right set left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using `position:sticky`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
}

.button {
  right: 0;
  margin-top:-5px;
  position: sticky;
  align-self:flex-start;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        Some content so long that it for sure overflows the container, and thus a horizontal scroll is needed.
      </div>
      <button class="button">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        Some content so long that it for sure overflows the container, and thus a horizontal scroll is needed.
        <br> This one is however a bit taller than the other items.
      </div>
      <button class="button">2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        Some content so long that it for sure overflows the container, and thus a horizontal scroll is needed.
      </div>
      <button class="button">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        Some content 
      </div>
      <button class="button">4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

it will be solved by a `position:sticky`